# use router angular 2 to show wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular

I would like to show http://localhost:4200/blog WordPress installation and plugin.
But when I navigate to this URL, angular 2 needs to assign component for that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this http://doppiaeast.com/article/angular-2-wordpress-theme-setup/

Comment: I have tried to navigate to  http://localhost:4200/blog and show wordpress plugin

Comment: Yes, but: What does your code and setup look like? Please explain in detail what you have tried so far (show your code!), and what exact issues you are having. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: The main question becomes from that when I navigated to  localhost:4200/blog angular2 starting to search some component  blog component. But I would like to show exactly for 'blog' only folders, it is posible to do?

Comment: You have to configure that in the backend.